# query to get element that has particular value using xpath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I doubt there is a way to get the element which has a particular value (text) from xml document using xpath.

#### Example doc:

```
<domain log-root="/logs" application-root="/applications"><resources>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="SamplePool" jndi-name="jdbc/sample" />
<jdbc-resource pool-name="TimerPool" jndi-name="abc">text1</jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="TimerPool" jndi-name="def">text2</jdbc-resource>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="TimerPool" jndi-name="ghi">text3</jdbc-resource></resources</domain>
```

#### Example xPath Query:

```
/domain//jdbc-resource[@pool-name='TimerPool']/text()='text2'
```

Please post your ideas if there is any.

Comment: Ultimately I would like to get the element "<jdbc-resource pool-name="TimerPool" jndi-name="def">text2</jdbc-resource>" as the result

Comment: Can you post me the document link which explains this kind of special tangs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/domain/*/jdbc-resource[@pool-name='TimerPool' and .='text2']
```

or you may use:

```
/domain/*/jdbc-resource[@pool-name='TimerPool'][.='text2']
```

Both expressions above select all `jdbc-resource` elements the string value of whose `pool-name` attribute is `"TimerPoool"` and whose string value (of the `jdbc-resource` element) is `"text2"` and that are grand-children of the top element of the XML document.

Comment: Post me the link that explains kind of syntax

Comment: @NageswaraRao: You are welcome. As for "the link that explains kind of syntax", I would recommend reading a good book. Here is my answer to a similar question (while the listed resources seem to be on XSLT, they also completely cover XPath, because XPath is "almost all" in XSLT:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: I understood xPath uses DOM inside. Is there a way to update the nodes and write back?

Comment: @NageswaraRao: Both your statement is genarally wrong and the answer to your question is negative. An XPath processor isn't obliged at all to use DOM, and in fact efficient XPath implementations, like .NET's `XPathDocument` don't use DOM. **XPath is a query language for XML documents and as such it is readonly**. Evaluation of an XPath query never changes an XML document and never produces altered nodes of the document.

Comment: Put it straight, I want to insert an element at a particular position. The position is based on the results I get using xPath.

Comment: @NageswaraRao: You can't do this simply by evaluating an XPath expression -- a program in your PL that is hosting the XPath engine must be involved. DOM can be used but this has a lot of shortcomings -- spaghetti-like code, difficult to understand and maintain, very difficult to write correctly and quite error-prone. XSLT is the best language for such tasks -- it is a language especially designed for tree (XML document) transformation. Your task is trivial to implement in XSLT.

Answer (score -1):

Well, text() should do. http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

Have you tried it already? Also, check the path, it could be

```
//jdbc-resource[@pool-name='TimerPool']/text()='text2'
```

or

```
/domain/resource/jdbc-resource[@pool-name='TimerPool']/text()='text2'
```

or

```
//resource/jdbc-resource[@pool-name='TimerPool']/text()='text2'
```